# Java Double Ended Queue toString Method overwriting left element

Tags: java, collections, queue, deque

I have created a double ended queue, and I want to print out the contents of my queue. I have created a toString method however when I add an element to the left it overwrites the current front(left) element.
For example

```
 System.out.println(myDeq);
 myDeq.addFront(7);
 myDeq.addRight(12);
 System.out.println(myDeq);
 myDeq.addFront(15);
 System.out.println(myDeq);
```

So my output would be

```
<>
<7,12>
<15,12>
```

But I want

```
<15,7,12>
```

My toString method is:

```
public String toString()
    { StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<");
        QCell<T> l = frontCell;
        QCell<T> r = backCell;
        while (l != null && r != null)
        { sb.append(l.data +"," + r.data + ",");
            l = l.next;
            r = r.next;
        }
        return(sb+">");
    }
```

My add to the left code is:
    @Override

```
public void addFront(T x) {
    QCell<T> theCell= new QCell<T>(x);
    if (frontCell == null)
        frontCell = backCell = theCell;
    else {
        frontCell.next = theCell;
        frontCell = theCell;
    }
}
```

I'm unsure if it is my toString method that is overwriting it or if my addFront code is incorrect.

Comment: why not write a unit test for your queue and find out?

Comment: @lance-java It isnt my add method, i tested it. It is my toString method but I can't figure out why it overwrites.

Comment: It doesn't matter who wrote it. Write a unit test which calls `add()` and `toString()` and make some assertions that should be true. Keep fixing the code until the test goes green.

Answer (score 1):

You addFront is wrong because you set frontCell's next to be theCell. But then reassigned frontCell to be theCell. So the original frontCell is no longer there. Save it in a tempCell first.

```
public void addFront(T x) {
    QCell<T> theCell= new QCell<T>(x);
    QCell<T> tempCell;
    if (frontCell == null)
        frontCell = backCell = theCell;
    else {
        tempCell = frontCell;
        frontCell = theCell;
        frontCell.next = tempCell;
    }
}
```

Also your backCell will be the lastCell so do not do `r = r.next;` as it should and will always be null; It should instead be `r.previous`.

Instead use a onesided loop traversing from front to back like this.

```
public String toString()
    { StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<");
        QueueCell<T> l = frontCell;
        while (l != null)
        { sb.append(l.data +",");
            l = l.next;
        }

        return(sb+">");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
frontCell.next = theCell;
```

be this instead?

```
theCell.next = frontCell;
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. I'm pretty sure it is my toString method that isn't correct because if i test my removeLeft method, the 7 is still there.

Comment: Yes, it's needlessly complex and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can't you just traverse the list from front to back? What is the `r` variable for?